# How to follow best Java practices using builder pattern for a subclass of an abstract superclass?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, builder, discord

```
// CommandBuilder.java
public class CommandBuilder {

 public String name; // required
 public String description = "Default Value"; //optional

 public CommandBuilder(String name) {
  this.name = name;
 }

 public CommandBuilder setDescription(String description) {
  this.description = description;
  return this;
 }

 public CommandBuilder build() {
  return this;
 }
}

// Command.java
public abstract class Command extends ListenerAdapter {

 private String name;
 private String description;

 protected abstract void execCommand(MessageReceivedEvent event);

 public Command(CommandBuilder builder) {
  this.name = builder.name;
  this.description = builder.description;
 }

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(MessageReceivedEvent event) {
   execCommand(event);
 }
}

// ExampleCommand.java
public class ExampleCommand extends Command {

 public ExampleCommand(CommandBuilder builder) {
  super(builder);
 }

 @Override
 protected void execCommand(MessageReceivedEvent event) {
  // ...
 }
}

// Bot.java
public class Bot() {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

  // ...
  jdaBuilder.addEventListener(
   new ExampleCommand(
    new CommandBuilder("Example Command").setDescription("You know it.").build();
   )
  );
  // ...
 }
}
```

So, I need some advice on code style. This above is roughly my code setup for a Discord bot in JDA. What `jdaBuilder.addEventListener(Object)` does or what `MessageReceivedEvent` is, is not important.

I use the builder pattern to avoid excessive constructor overloading when constructing objects with the inherited type `Command`, because in my actual code the `Command` class can accept far more than just two parameters.
The issue with `CommandBuilder` is that `build()` doesn't and can't return an object of type `Command` (because it's abstract) but rather the type `CommandBuilder` itself, that each subclass of Command takes as an argument (and then passes on to `Command`).
The problem with THAT in return is that:

1. Calling `build()` is not required because every single other method returns a `CommandBuilder`aswell
2. Instantiation of a subclass of `Command` with 4-6 parameters can get *very* messy in the main.

So, what's the best way to solve this? I thought of using an interface, but in my abstract Command class there are certain methods with "default" code, that the subclasses can choose to override if they need it (but it's not required!). 
These default methods utilize the other methods of the `Command` class, so I can't just refactor them into the interface as true default methods.

My code works just fine, I just think that with the way I have to instantiate my objects, I did a wrong turn somewhere. Any advice on how to refactor or rewrite my code to follow best Java practices?

Comment: TLDR; Directly to the question - just follow them.

Comment: My question is how, not why. I know that a Builder should always return the object it was designed to build, but that isn't possible in my case, which leads to me having to work around it by having the builder return itself. That in turn makes for really long and awkward instantiation code.

Comment: First off it's not really clear what you're after. Regarding your code it's very interesting to see that your Builder does not actually build anything. Seems to be a container for properties, but that's not the actual intention of the Builder pattern. Builders should ease construction of complex objects, i.e. their output depends on the given properties or just delay construction of a concrete object. Your builder does not seem to do anything like this, so it looks like a wrong approach. Maybe a rewrite of your question would help.

Comment: Use a smart builder; on certain options, for example `withFieldOnlyMagicCommandHas` switch to a `MagicCommandBuilder`. For examples, see the Spring Security JavaConfig code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you shoud refactor your `build()` like this:

```
public <T extends Command> T build(Function<CommandBuilder, T> constructor) {
    return constructor.apply(this);
}
```

and this way allow the builder to accept any constructor reference such as

```
FooCommand cmd = builder.build(FooCommand::new);
```

Maybe additionally you could add proper code to alternatively allow for reflection so that

```
FooCommand cmd = builder.build(FooCommand.class);
```

would usable as well, but the former one has the advantage that it is a compile time error if you don't have a matching constructor.

Comment: Thank you. One late question, do you think that this is good design or that it's kinda hacky?

Comment: @Mikusch It is IMHO a good way to tell the builder what kind of object to build. I think it is a good design.